# How can one use 'would' and 'could' both, consecutively?

Tags: modal-verbs, sentence-patterns, australian-english, would, could

I encountered a sentence in an article. The writer (an Australian) has used both 'could' and 'would' consecutively in a sentence.

The sentence is

> But I was determined to make a statement: would could do this, instruction manual be damned.

Is this usage correct? If yes, what is the structure used in the sentence?

[image: extract from article]

Comment: It’s a typo.  It should be ***we*** could do this...

Comment: A typo for "we could" certainly seems the most likely explanation. You sometimes get would and could together in expressions such as "woulda coulda shoulda", to refer to hypotheticals, but that doesn't seem to fit here. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/woulda,_coulda,_shoulda

Comment: Could 'would' be used in a sentence where 'could' and 'would' were juxtaposed ?

Comment: Would 'could' fit into a sentence so that it was immediately after 'would' ?

Comment: @NigelJ Most anything is possible when you ignore the use-mention distinction.

Comment: 'I would that I could ...' seems the wrong register to headlinese.

Comment: Isn't it the job of humor to break rules? It's no more than a funny mash-up of "I not only would but could, so there" used for a shock effect.

Answer (score 0):

Some dialects do employ "double modals". See [Yale University's Multiple modals](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/multiple-modals) and [other resources](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=double+modals+in+english&atb=v198-1zk&ia=web).

Example: He might should have been there.

Standard English does not employ double modals. I am unaware if any dialect in Australian English employs double motives or whether this Australian was imitating double modal usage(s) he heard in another English dialect.

It's quite possible that double modals are used somewhere in Australia, given that they are used in certain nonstandard varieties of both American English and British English.